# Match characters in a line and print the line before python

Tags: python, file, enumerate

I have a log file, this file is like this:

> line1 input
>
> line2 output
>
> line3 input
>
> line4 output
>
> and so on...

Based on the output I want to extract both input and output to a new file..

As a sample code I used print and the method .startswith, and that's fine by me, because I'm only interested in how can I pull the current line in a file and the line before it.

Here is how I've done:

```
file = 'path_to_file'
index_list = []
line_list = []

with open(file) as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        line_list.append(line)
        if line.startswith('b'):
            index_list.append(index)

        
for index in index_list:
    print line_list[index-1], line_list[index]
```

This code works just fine, but I wondered if there's a more pythonic way to do it, saving memory.

Thank you in advance.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without storing more than two lines in memory:

```
from itertools import izip

with open('test.log') as lines:
    for input_line, output_line in izip(lines):
        if output_line.startswith('b'):
            print input_line
            print output_line
```

Put it into a function and replace `print` by `yield` and you can use `file.writelines()` with that function to write just the matching input/output pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the lines of a file in a list. Then you can easily retrieve the line and the previous line. Also I suggest not running this in the REPL since large log file may slow down the python REPL.

```
with open(fileName) as file:
    content = file.readlines()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A large log file may not only slow down the REPL but any program that reads the whole file into memory. Even the whole system's performance could suffer if the process starts swapping.